# Monitor will not stay off

Tags: windows-10, display, power-management

I am having this issue where the monitor will not turn off even though Windows power options are configured for it to turn off after a specified period of time.

In testing, I configured the timeout to 1 minute and waited for the monitor to turn off. The monitor will look like it will turn off, but it turns back on after a few seconds! I also tried third party software to turn off the monitor like [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and [turn off monitor](http://turnoffmonitor.com/), but both of these exibited the same behavior. I have also tried running nircmd in safe mode, but once again, the monitor flashes off then on.

In an attempt to diagnose this, I made sure to unplug everything from the PC except for the power and display cable, however, the same thing occurred. Additionally, I have disabled wake timers and wake on lan. There are no game controllers connected the the PC as well.

This issue is extremely puzzling. Everything that I have tried will not solve the problem.

This PC is an HP Compaq 6200 running Windows 10 LTSB 2016.

Comment: I have the same problem.  In my case it is a piece of software keeping the computer awake upon entering sleep.  There is no fix I have found on my end other than not using that software.

Comment: What piece of software was it? How were you able to diagnose it?

Comment: Resilio Sync.  Cant remember how I diagnosed it; its been a while.  I gave up on it quickly.  There might have been a hack solution and/or it might be unique to my setup/programs and setting, but I need my files to sync more importantly that my computer sleeping and I actually use everything installed.

Comment: @Damon You are definitely right it is some piece of software. I just did a clean install and the issue was gone. The weird thing about this is that this is a fresh install with just a few pieces of software that I installed. I guess I will just uninstall everything one by one...

Comment: After much testing, I have found that it was not any third party software that was causing this. I removed all software that I had installed, however, the issue still persisted. Using msconfig, I was able to determine the "Power" service by Microsoft was the root cause leading me to believe the OS files may be corrupted.

Comment: You might answer your own question with details of how you came to your conclusion and, of course, your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error by removing and stopping services, I was finally able to learn that the service causing the issue was the "Power" service by Microsoft. This, however, is a core service that runs as part of Windows. Without it, power plans and automatic monitor sleeping would not work. However, the monitor will still turn off manually by using nircmd.

Using dism and sfc /scannow, did not fix the issue with the Windows installation. The method that was able to fix the issue was an in-place upgrade using the original Windows ISO. This rewrote the Windows files while still leaving the applications and data intact.

EDIT:
Upon reinstalling Windows and reconfiguring my settings, I noticed that this issue was once again occurring leading me to believe it was a setting that I changed. After some thought, I was able to discover that the real issue was due to the ForceAutoLogon setting in the registry I had applied. This prevents the monitor from turning off.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, found that it was the gamepad that was preventing the monitor from turning off. Found the solution here

https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-monitor-wont-sleep/